# In C# how can I automate testing of Word find/replace code?

Tags: c#, automated-tests, word-automation

I have an application in C# that automates the filling out of forms in Word from a Database.
I'm currently adding unit-testing to my application. there are a lot of calls to `Replace(...)`, which is a "simple" wrapper for `Range.Find.Execute(..)`. I have several other, more complex methods, that are just fancy wrappers to `Replace(...)` I have most of them in the same class `WordWrapper` which also handles the allocation and de-allocation of the `WordApplication` object and the open `Document` list.  What is a good method for Automating the testing of something like that?

I especially want to make sure my Allocation and de-allocation are properly handled, and that I get appropriate Error Messages/Exceptions when things go wrong talking to Word.

**UPDATE:** The reason I'm worried about the Allocation/De-Allocation is that, Word is an expensive object to create/destroy, so I've made it static so I can re-use it between invocations of the form window that actually runs word.

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend that this NOT be an automated testing function.

I've worked on many such systems and quite frankly there are things that occur in text replacement that an automated solution just won't find.  You are much better off drafting a number of colleagues in the affected business unit to QA the updates.

One example: Let's say the form has enough space for 6 characters.  You inject 10.  The find / replace code obviously worked.  However, because the amount of characters ran over, it completely jacked the structure of the page and what was a 1 pager now has 2 pages...which will probably not be acceptable.

**UPDATE:** I'm going to leave this answer simply because it might help someone in the future stumbling through the concept of find/replacing text in documents.  However, after rereading the question (along with its update), I don't think this answer really applies at all.

Comment: On the other hand, there are things that an automated solution will find. For instance, I would at least like some reassurance that later replacements do not mess with former replacements. Even with a limited number of chained text replacements I find it very hard to tell if it is safe to add another one. Unit tests on content could be useful here, don't you think?

Comment: I disagree with the "Don't make automated tests, use QAs" approach. Why can't it be both? They both serve different purposes.

Comment: @GertArnold: The best you can do with automated is ensure that the function call worked.  Meaning that your code said "replace text" and it didn't fail.  Beyond that everything else must be caught by a visual inspection of the final document.

Comment: @Chris. And that's exactly what visual inspection, however useful (sure), will miss. But we're (I'm) a bit off-topic, I'm afraid. Poor Raystorm hasn't got an answer yet: *I especially want to make sure my Allocation (...) when things go wrong talking to Word.*

Comment: @Chris I do have test users, that was my original solution, and will still be part of my final solution.  I'm just looking for a way to test as much of my application as possible, so as many errors/bugs get caught, before I ever get to the stage of releasing to my test users.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to test that you handle errors and exception from Word correctly then your best bet it to create a mock interface for your tests.

This looks like the real interface, but you can control what each call will return so, for example, if you pass "Find xyz" it will return "true", but if you pass "Find 123" it will raise an exception. You can then verify that your code handles this correctly.

I don't know of any mocking framework that explicitly targets Word however.